# How to load data into a specific partition in a partitioned table

Tags: sql-server-2014

Is there any way to load data into a specific partition of partitioned table.What I am looking for something like 'insert into a_partitioned_table.partition....'.
So I can avoid overhead happening for sql server scanning for appropriate partition.

Thanks

Comment: If the destination partition is empty, you can use alter table switch partition, but if it's not empty, I'm afraid there is no way to indicate destination partition

Comment: Thanks for your comment.The destination partition is empty.But source table is not partitioned.

Comment: If the destination partition is empty, your table resides on the same filegroup with destination partition, all you need is to define check constraint on your source table and then you can use alter table..switch to ...partition n

Answer (score 0):

you can query like
insert into target_table
partition (partitions_column_name of target_table)
select * from another_table where partition='888888';